# Display a link and by clicking on that all the new products should be displayed like category view page in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, product

I am displaying all the **NEW** products on the homepage through Widget. I am displaying **3 NEW** Products on the homepage. I want to put a **link** under products display. By clicking on that link, all the products should be displayed in a separate page. What do I give **href** of that link??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a CMS page for NEW products from admin and on href give the link to that page.

Comment: thnx very much @Shatir .. It worked perfectly, I just had to setup the layout. :)